# Start service on click

Tags: android, firebase, android-service, android-manifest

this is my manifest app:

```
  <!-- [START firebase_service] -->
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END firebase_service] -->
    <!-- [START firebase_iid_service] -->
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END firebase_iid_service] -->
```

now,the default when run app the service start

but i do not want.i want when click on button start service
what must to do?

Comment: This is just how it works. Learn to work with it :-)